# Laravel 5.7 Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, actionlink

I am working with an existing database where I have a table named `pnc_members`

Because laravel interprets that name incorrectly I placed

```php
protected $table = 'pnc_members';
```

in the `pnc_members.php` model to solve that problem.

In my controller I get the table data with

```
$members = pnc_members::paginate(10);
```

however; I get an error in the view `members.blade.php` when I insert the pagination link

```php
{{ $members->links() }}
```

> The error is 
>   ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Call to undefined method App\Models\pnc_members::links() (View: C:\wamp64\www\pnc-system\resources\views\members.blade.php)
>   Previous exceptions
>   Call to undefined method App\Models\pnc_members::links()

So it seems like it is confusing `$members` with the protect directive for the table!

I've tried changing the variable to another name used in the get (i.e. $members_pg) and it still does not work!

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: plz post your whole action code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I added a line to the controller **$pages = $members->links();**
then used **dd($pages);** to see what it captured and that looked good.

The returned view adding array with the $pages variable to be passed to the blade as follows: **return view('members', ['pages' => $pages])->with('members', $members);**

I then put {{$pages} into my blade and it works perfectly.

Why it does not work the other way I don't really know, but at least I got it resolved.

Thanks//

Answer (score 0):

If your table is pnc_members, your Model name must be PncMember.

So first of all make sure you have this model 
and then in your controller you can use

```
$members = PncMember::paginate(5);
```

Comment: That did not work ta ble name ends with an 's' and if I change it then Iit can't find controller. My workaround where I capture the link in the controller as a variable that I pass to the blade works for me. I have that same problem with other blades and just to run it in they all have table names ending with an 's'. When I have more time I will try other things, but right now I'm OK with the work around that is working in all my blades. Thanks for your assistance//